# Use column value as column name when inserting (Clickhouse)

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a source table:

| Data |
| --- |
| 122435 |
| 2912 |
| 32 |

I want to select data from this table and insert into a destination table. The desired output for the destination table is:

| Index_1 | Index_2 | Index_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 9 |  |
|  |  | 2 |

The logic behind this is numbers in odd positions are indexes (columns), and numbers in even positions are values:

```
1) "122435" -> "12", "24", "35" -> "Index_1 = 2", "Index_2 = 4", "Index_3 = 5"
2) "2912" -> "29", "12" -> "Index_2 = 9", "Index_1 = 2"
3) "32" -> "Index_3 = 2"
```

My problem is I don't know if it is possible to use column value as column name in Clickhouse.

Comment: I would like to propose split from one query to two queries
first query select indexes
second construct SQL query from selected indexes

Comment: @Slach Is it possible to construct SQL query only using SQL without code? If so, then, please, provide SQL, thanks!